# Find defined value in object types

Tags: typescript

So I have this issue where I have an array of modifications that need to be applied to a certain object:

```
interface Mods {
    merge?: MergeModSettings,
    offset?: OffsetModSettings,
    split?: SplitModSettings,
    .....
}

type PathMods = Mods[];
```

So right now I'm having trouble to get this typesafe.

```
const getMod = <V extends Mods, K extends keyof V>(mod: V): { modType: K, modSettings: V[K]} => {
  const match = Object.keys(mod).find((k) => isNotNullOrUndefined(mod[k as K]));

  if (!match){
    throw new Error('ERROR')
  }

  return {
    modType: match as K,
    modSettings: mod[match as K]
  }
}


const {modType, modSettings} = getMod(mod)

switch(modType) {
    case 'merge': 
    // Here I expect the type of modSettings to be MergeModSettings 
    // but its 'MergeModSettings | OffsetModSettings | SplitModSettings'.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
interface MergeMod {
    modType: "merge"
    merge: MergeModSettings
}
interface OffsetMod {
    modType: "offset"
    offset: OffsetModSettings
}
interface SplitMod {
    modType: "split"
    split: SplitModSettings
}
type Mod = MergeMod | OffsetMod | SplitMod

const m: Mod = // ...

switch (m.modType) {
    case "merge":
    // Here 'm' is of type 'MergeMod'
}
```

Notice: When you destructure a variable, the destructured variable types are not linked anymore. You can't test one (`modType`) in order to deduce the type of the other (`modSettings`).